# Redirect from one webpage to another page on few dates and particular time intervals

Tags: php, redirect

I've a registration page with payment on my website. The application is currently running, but Centre will be conducting a series of network maintenance on 5 Saturdays, around 4 hours per day.

On these days Online Collections System will only be available intermittently. So I want to redirect my registration page to some other page only on these particular dates and times.

Is there any secure and simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your problem you have to define maintenance times previously.

```
$mainStage = 0;// Change this value with maintenance stage 
$maintenanceTime = array(
  0=>array('start'=>'5.00','end'=>'13.00'),
  1=>array('start'=>'6.00','end'=>'12.00'));
if($maintenanceTime[$mainStage]['start'] < date('G.i') && $maintenanceTime[$mainStage]['end'] > date('G.i'))
header("location:maintenance/new/url");
```